# C++ Simple calculation outputting 0.0000000000000000 instead of 0.003333

Tags: c++, glm-math

The calculation for dx and dy is returning 0 and I don't see what the issue is.  The console seems to show all the correct values are being used.

```
void drawBackground()
{
    double r, g, b, dx, dy, Wx, Wy, Wz; 
    Ray ray;
    cout << "xmax: " << sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmax << " xmin: " << sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmin << endl;
    cout << "ymax: " << sceneDescription::imagePlaneYmax << " ymin: " << sceneDescription::imagePlaneYmin << endl;
    cout << "Iw: " << sceneDescription::Iw << " Ih: " << sceneDescription::Ih << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;

    dx = (sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmax - (sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmin))/sceneDescription::Iw;
    dy = (sceneDescription::imagePlaneYmax - (sceneDescription::imagePlaneYmin))/sceneDescription::Ih;
    std::cout << "dx: "<< boost::format("%1$.16f") % dx << " dy: "<< boost::format("%1$.16f") % dy << endl;

}
```

sceneDescription.h

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

class sceneDescription{

public:
    static const int imagePlaneXmin = -1;
    static const int imagePlaneXmax = 1;
    static const int imagePlaneYmin = -1;
    static const int imagePlaneYmax = 1;
    static const int Iw = 600;
    static const int Ih = 800;
};
```

Console output:

```
xmax: 1 xmin: -1

ymax: 1 ymin: -1

Iw: 600 Ih: 800


dx: 0.0000000000000000 dy: 0.0000000000000000
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, what were the values before calculation and after?  Which line is giving the issue?

Comment: Have you check for integer division before conversion to floating point?

Comment: It looks like the lines setting dx and dy are using integer arithmetic because all the variables in sceneDescription are ints

Comment: try `dx = 1.0*(sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmax - (sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmin))/sceneDescription::Iw;` and similarly for `dy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the statement:

```
dx = (sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmax -
(sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmin))/sceneDescription::Iw;
```

will give the following result:

```
(1-(-1))/600 = 2/600 = 0.00 (since this is integer division).
```

You may want to cast the number to `double`.

Something like this would work:

```
dx = (double)(sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmax -
(sceneDescription::imagePlaneXmin)) / sceneDescription::Iw;
```

Since cast operator has higher priority than division, the numerator will be cast by `(double)` and the denominator will be cast implicitly giving the `double` result.

Hope that helps!